# Cannot access SMC8014WG-SI provided by TimeWarner/RoadRunner administrative interface

Tags: router, wireless-router, smc

I just received installation of RoadRunner internet/TV/Voice and I was given a wi-fi router from the TimeWarner folks. The model is a SMC SMC8014WG-SI. Unfortunately, the password it uses is WEP and that is, as we all know, completely insecure. The tech that was here didn't know how to change it to something like WPA2 w/TKIP, and I was on hold for 20 minutes with the TimeWarner folks before I gave up.

My problem is that the default web interface (http://192.168.0.1) isn't responding. I can ping it, I can access the internet through it, but I can't get to the admin interface. I did a "hard reset" of the device but still no dice. My suspicion is that the wi-fi admin interface is disabled (a common setting) but the wired interface isn't working on either of my two laptops (I've tried two laptops with two different cables, no link light activated).

Am I SOL? Did they lock this down so I can't do what I want to do? Worst-case is I just hook up my go-to WRT54G router to the other modem and leave this one turned off, but I'd rather use their hardware to avoid any "It's not our problem" in the future. Any thoughts? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran NMAP on the internal interface. This is a port scanner (security scanner). http https ssh and telnet are filtered, they have an access rule on it to prevent admin access. port 8081 is also open, but doesn't seem to respond. This is a Stupid move by time warner Now I'm stuck with a unsecure wep network and a random ssid. I called time warner on this per my later post.

Called time warner. Apparently their possition is that the product was designed for idiots that don't understand wireless. How it is easier to connect to 5fde and enter a 32 charactor wep key is beyond me. As such they will not allow you to change this, or change it for you. Thank you level 3 support. They will not give you access to the router. They will not change the ssid or security settings.
Time warner now has a corporate policy which is endangering their costumers. They have decided that all their costumers should use wep and a random ssid, which is not best pratice at all. Wep isn't secure at all, and is easilly exploytable. According to TW level 3 it appears the only option is to return this stupid paperweight and get a modem with your own router. I'm mythed by this. They have no care or concern for the security of costumer networks, and are exposing all of their costumers networks and information.

**Update:**

Looks like this is move to secure their network. 
Apparently this router has java vulnerabilities that allowed anyone to access the admin portion of the router. So they locked this down, so you can't access it either.
SO time warner cut off all access remote or otherwise.
If you have one of these routers. RETURN IT. On my new order they were charging $6.99 a month for it (of which I wasn't aware).
A better wireless g router can be had for very cheap.You will not have to deal with time warners stupidity or inability to provide you secure service. Wep isn't secure. Connecting to a random ssid Isn't convient.

Comment: This is what I did. I returned the router and picked up a cheap LinkSys; I had no idea it was even charging me EXTRA for this less than useless device (opening malicious users up to my network, too!). At least now I can pick WPA-2 w/TKIP. Sheesh.

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using?  It may not support firefox or chrome.  Also did you make sure that your http proxy was disabled?  According to thier [documentation](http://www.smc.com/files/AE/UG_SMC8014WG-SI.pdf) you cannot access the router with it enabled.  Also try using 192.168.100.1.  That is the typical address of accessing cable modems, although I don't think that is the issue here.  Good luck!